# Regex in Notepad++ to replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the follow text in a document (using Notepad++).

Now, I want to replace all regex occurence with a ?.

I have:

```
'{$data}', '{$data2}', '{$res}','{$blahblahblah}'
```

And I want them to become ?,?,?,?

I tried using `\b^'{(.+)}'$\b`  but that doesn't seem to find the pattern.

Comment: You should not use `^` and `$` here..

Comment: You should use `\{\$.+?\}` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the anchors and word boundaries. And it would be perfect if you escape the braces.

```
'\{\$.*?\}'
```

Then replace the match with a `?` symbol.

Comment: I think the cause of the problem of the OP is also escaping the curly braces, don't you?

Comment: Ironically, this was the solution that work for Notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
'{\$[^}]+}'
```

And replace with `?`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hZ8tH4/4)

Explanation:

- `'{\$` match quote, curly brace and `$` literls
- `[^}]+}` negated character class to match anything other than `}` more than once (`+`) followed by `}`... Equivalent to `.*?}` but 2-3 times faster